# How to check if a string is a valid variable name in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, validation, variable-names

I would like to get some reusable code to correctly determine whether or not a string is a valid variable name in python3 (or the currently-running python would suffice).

For example:

If given the string `group_찇籸딥햳㸙濮ᚨ麍ڵថ`, the method that solves this problem should return `True`, this can be used as a python variable name. If given `group_찇籸딥-햳㸙濮ᚨ麍ڵថ`, it should return `False`, because it cannot be used correctly as a singular variable name.

```
>>> group_찇籸딥햳㸙濮ᚨ麍ڵថ = 4
>>> group_찇籸딥-햳㸙濮ᚨ麍ڵថ = 4
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: can't assign to operator
```

I would prefer if the solution avoided unsafe `eval`s. A previously-attempted solution was returning `True` if the regex `^[\d\W]|[^\w]` was matched, but this seems to be incomplete since it mis-identifies the first example given above as invalid.

Comment: Hello @AlanSE, I see you want to avoid `eval`, but what about the `literal_eval` function from the `ast` package ?

Comment: @BertrandGazanion That would be fine to use. Even with the use of that I'm still somewhat unsure of how to address this in an airtight way.

Comment: I tried the ast.literal_eval approach but it is not working for the first example for me.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the below provided `is_pyname(s)` function able to determine whether a string is a valid variable name in Python 3 using three methods:

- the `regex` (not in Python distribution yet provided) module supporting `\p{L}`, `\p{N}` matching all Unicode characters considered to be respectively Letters, Numbers (i.e. digits) and an appropriate regex pattern
- running `exec(s)` in a `try/except` block
- checking if `tokeninfo.string == s` where tokeninfo was created with help of the tokenize module

```
def is_pyname(s, method=None):
    if method == 'regex' or method is None: 
        import regex
        # ^-- regex supports \p{L} and \p{N} which match 
        # ^-- Unicode chars considered to be Letters and Numbers
        is_name_by_regex = False
        if regex.findall(r"\p{L}[\p{L}\p{N}_]*",s)[0] == s:
            is_name_by_regex = True
        if method == 'regex':
            return is_name_by_regex
    # ---
    if method == 'exec' or method is None:
        is_name_by_exec = False 
        try:
            exec(s+'=None')
            is_name_by_exec = True
        except SyntaxError:
            pass
        if method == 'exec':
            return is_name_by_exec
    # ---
    if method == 'tokens' or method is None:
        from io       import BytesIO  as bio
        from tokenize import tokenize as tknz
        #from token import tok_name
        is_name_by_tokens = False
        #mlnTxt = '\n'.join([str(t) for t in tknz(bio(s.encode()).readline)])
        #print(mlnTxt)
        for tokeninfo in tknz(bio(s.encode()).readline): 
            #print(f'{tokeninfo.type:3d} ({tok_name[tokeninfo.type]:10s}), {str(tokeninfo)}')
            if tokeninfo.string == s: # .type .string .start .end .line
                is_name_by_tokens = True
                break
        if method == 'tokens':
            return is_name_by_tokens
    # ---
    assert is_name_by_regex == is_name_by_exec == is_name_by_tokens
    #print('assertion OK')
    is_name = is_name_by_regex
    return is_name


print(is_pyname('찇籸딥햳㸙濮ᚨ麍ڵថ'))  # True
print(is_pyname('찇籸딥-햳㸙濮ᚨ麍ڵថ')) # False
print(is_pyname('7seven'))           # False
```