# Regex to match variable assignment of multiple variables in Python syntax?

Tags: python, regex

I am reading whole Python files as single strings, compiling the expressions in multiline-mode. So far I have been able to match single variable assignment with Python regex:

```
"^\s*[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z_0-9]*\s*(?=\=)(?!==)"
```

- `^\s*`: First it checks if variable assignment is on a new line followed by spaces. I do this to prevent syntax such as `foo(required=True, thud=3)`from matching, as I do not define those as variable assignments.
- `[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z_0-9]*`: Then it looks for a valid variable name...
- `\s*(?=\=)(?!==)`: ...and sees if variable name is followed by `=` and not by `==`, as it is a comparison and not a variable assignment.

This works fine, but not for assignment of multiple variables in a single line:

```
a, b = 4, 5
```

In this case the regex will not match either of the variables. Note that it should not match the `,`, only `a` and `b` separately. How to do this?

Comment: Try `(?:(?<=\W)|^)[^\W\d]\w*\s*(?:,\s*[^\W\d]\w*\s*)*(?==(?!=))`

Comment: You are saying should not match commas, only variable names, but I can't see capturing groups in your regex.

Comment: @ctwheels That was really fast haha. Problem is it matches `a, b`, and not `a` and `b` separately...

Comment: Ah, when I have difficulties in regex I always use this service https://regex101.com, remember to mark Python in sidebar as the regex flavor.

Comment: @Snusifer best approach would then to split on `\s*,\s*`

Comment: @WagnerMacedo regex101 is what i am using. You can match them separately without groups, using re.finditer()

Comment: With the BOS part `^\s*` the regex is restricted to start at one place. With the `(?==)(?!==)` part the regex is forced to match a equals at the end. So not going to match anything but for example this `" _BDK90hr `="

Comment: Python supports many more syntaxes: `[a]=[a,*b]=(a,[b])=a,=…`.

Comment: Are extracting variable name? you should your code at least to explain what you mean by matching a b separately?

Answer (score 0):

Python accepts in variable names any Unicode characters marked as letters and/or numbers and the underscore. The standard re module coming with Python does not support appropriate escape sequences necessary to create a regex pattern able to match a variable name, but there exists a Python regex module supporting them.

Check out [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74355251/7711283) to the *How to check if a string is a valid variable name in Python?* question for an appropriate regex pattern you can then use in an attempt to construct the regex pattern for the assignment.

One of the methods validating a Python variable name I have used in my above mentioned answer is usage of the tokenize module. I recommend to check out this module for inspiration how to achieve your goal by making use of this module instead of looking for a regular expression able to duplicate Python parsing capabilities.